# Entitydatasource EF6 Boolean [ERROR]

Tags: asp.net, oracle, boolean, entitydatasource

In VS2015 im using web application with OracleDB and i'm trying to do the connection with Entitydatasource wizard.Everything works fine and smooth even though i have EF6 but if any of the tables im trying to load has a Boolean type (number(1,0) in database) the wizard crashes(It says that its only compatible with ef5 etc..).

I tried to change the type from model properties to int16 but then project throws error for wrong mapping.I read somewhere that EntityDatasource recognize true or false for Boolean but its mapped by default from oracle to recognize Boolean as number(1,0). So i guess there is a conflict there.

Comment: So basically you use incompatible technologies and they happen to work in a specific scenario, now you want to know how to make them work in a different scenario instead of switching to compatible technologies?

Comment: Well they work on every scenario except having a boolean type on table you loaded in Model.I have installed some nuget and maybe the incompatible technologies are working so i dont really know why it works..but it is.!What technology i should use instead?

Comment: This doesn't work in the way you want and is more complex. You need the driver and the connector of the specific database and in this case, the specific EF library, por e.g. MySQL has its EF itself.